# Dynamically Adjusting Bottom Sheet Opening Based on Content in React Native Using Gohrom BottomSheet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently using the Gohrom BottomSheet library in my React Native application to implement a bottom sheet feature. I've been using the size prop to define the snap point at which the bottom sheet opens. However, I'm now looking to modify it to automatically adjust the opening of the bottom sheet depending on the content inside it.

Here's a snippet of my current implementation:

```
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetBackdrop, BottomSheetScrollView } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { Portal } from '@gorhom/portal';
import React, { FC, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { heightPixel } from '../../styles';
import { customBottomSheetStyles } from './style';
import { CustomBottomSheetPropsType } from './types';

const CustomBottomSheet: FC<CustomBottomSheetPropsType> = ({ children, size, onClose }) => {
  const { StatusBarManager } = NativeModules;
  const bottomInset = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? -heightPixel(StatusBarManager.HEIGHT) : 0;
  const bottomSheetSize =
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? heightPixel(size) + heightPixel(20)
      : heightPixel(size) + heightPixel(StatusBarManager.HEIGHT);
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);
  bottomSheetRef.current?.snapToIndex(0);
  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback(
    (index: number) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        bottomSheetRef.current?.close();
        onClose();
      }
    },
    [onClose]
  );

  return (
    <Portal>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={1}
        onClose={onClose}
        snapPoints={[bottomSheetSize, bottomSheetSize]}
        onChange={handleSheetChanges}
        enablePanDownToClose
        style={customBottomSheetStyles.bottomSheetContainer}
        bottomInset={bottomInset}
        backdropComponent={(props) => (
          <BottomSheetBackdrop
            style={customBottomSheetStyles.backdropContainer}
            {...props}
            opacity={0.2}
            appearsOnIndex={0}
            disappearsOnIndex={-1}
          />
        )}
      >
        <BottomSheetScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} nestedScrollEnabled={true} scrollEnabled={true}>
          {children}
        </BottomSheetScrollView>
      </BottomSheet>
    </Portal>
  );
};

export { CustomBottomSheet };
```

I want to adjust the opening of the bottom sheet dynamically based on the content inside it rather than relying on a fixed size prop. How can I achieve this dynamically within my React Native application?